# Query for latest version of records in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in Microsoft Access that is pulling from a Sql Server view.  There is a revision level field that is a type char(2).  So, an object could have multiple revisions starting with "01", then "02", and on up.  I would like to get just the latest revision records for each object.  Is there a way to setup the query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
SELECT DataTable.ItemName, DataTable.Revision
FROM DataTable
WHERE (((DataTable.Revision)=(select max(revision) from DataTable T where T.ItemName=DataTable.ItemName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in one step with SQL. Rather you need to find the right revision for each Product first and then get the records, that match those Product/Revision pairs:

To find the Revision for each product, you want to group by product and find the highest related revision:

```
SELECT Test.ProductID, Max(Test.Revision) AS MaxOfRevision
FROM Test
GROUP BY Test.ProductID;
```

Only now you can go to the original dataset and get every record that matches our newly found ProductID/Revision pair:

```
SELECT Test.TestID, Test.ProductID, Test.Description
FROM Test 
INNER JOIN 
    subQ 
ON (Test.Revision = subQ.MaxOfRevision) AND (Test.ProductID = subQ.ProductID);
```

Of course you can create a Query that contains both:

```
SELECT Test.TestID, Test.ProductID, Test.Description
FROM Test 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Test.ProductID, Max(Test.Revision) AS MaxOfRevision
     FROM Test
     GROUP BY Test.ProductID) AS subq
ON (Test.Revision = subQ.MaxOfRevision) AND (Test.ProductID = subQ.ProductID);
```

### Explanation:

The only way to find the highest value in a column is with Max(). `SELECT Max(Revision) FROM table;` gives us exactly one value: the highest occurring `revision` in all records. The DBEngine looks at every `revision` it finds and takes the highest one.

If we want to have the highest revision of every Product, we need to group by product. The DBEngine now walks through the table once for every ProductID, looks at each `revision` it finds in the respective records, takes the highest one and associates it with its Product-Group.

That is why the resulting records of the first query cannot contain all the desired data: they are not a subset of the original ones, they are new records that have one group-designator (the ProductID) and one `revision`-value: the highest out of all `revision`values the DBEngine could find in relation to that Product.

### Sidenote

As long as you have the leading zeroes in your revisions you can just use Max() here because incidentally it sorts the same way as numbers would. In a future application you might want to replace that field with a number field or convert it explicitly to numbers before using it like a number (MAX, Sort....).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following sub select also works.

```
SELECT  *
  FROM DataTable 
  INNER JOIN (  
    SELECT  JobNumber , 
        MAX(CAST(RevisionLevel AS INT)) AS MaxRevision 
    FROM    DataTable 
    GROUP BY JobNumber)x 
  ON x.JobNumber = DataTable.JobNumber AND CAST(DataTable.RevisionLevel AS INT) = x.MaxRevision
```